# How to only copy rows of data that haven't been copied to other workbook yet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search for specific strings within my spreadsheet, and if found, copy the entire row of data where it was found to a different workbook -- this part is working fine.  VBA is not a language I'm comfortable with at all, and I inherited this code as a starting point -- My main issue is that it doesn't yet check to see if that row of data has been copied to the other workbook before copying.  So each time it runs (at save) it copies all the criteria-meeting rows over again.

```
'Search code
LastRow = Alpha.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Loop search code
For i = 2 To LastRow

   'Compare columns for mismatches
    If Alpha.Range("F" & i) <> Alpha.Range("G" & i) Then

   'Pull out mismatches if contain specific text
    Select Case True
       'Search for specific text
        Case (InStr(1, Alpha.Range("G" & i), "ABC") > 0)
       'Move mismatched row to next empty row in TrackSheet
            NextRow = TrackSheet.Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Alpha.Rows(i).Copy
            TrackSheet.Rows(NextRow).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    End Select
    End If

Next i
```

Any help would be SO greatly appreciated!!!  I have been searching the forums all day and don't have a good enough grip on VBA to tailor any solutions to my own code.

Comment: You'd need to explain exactly how you'd know if a row has already been copied.  Is there some uniquely-identifying column or set of columns, or you want to match on the whole row?

Comment: Whatever is easier - I don't currently have a unique identifier on each row, but could easily add a column for that if it would make things more efficient than checking the entire row.

Comment: How would you perform the check manually right now?

Comment: I wouldn't have a real way yet (still just using test data so I know it keeps adding and adding the test rows whenever I run it).  You are right, I need to add a unique column - It'll be column A.  Still just not sure how to tell VBA to check the other workbook and only copy the row when identifier from column A hasn't already been copied there yet

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both sheets have a unique Id in ColA, you can use `Match` to check for an existing row:

```
Dim CoderBook As Workbook
Dim CDIreview As Workbook
Dim Ophth As Worksheet
Dim VERA As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim i As Long, m

'Search code
LastRow = Ophth.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Loop search code
For i = 2 To LastRow

   'Compare columns for mismatch
    If Ophth.Range("F" & i) <> Ophth.Range("G" & i) Then

   'Pull out specific high priority mismatches
    Select Case True
       'Search strings in column H for high priority mismatches
        Case (InStr(1, Ophth.Range("G" & i), "H54") > 0)
            'Move mismatched row to next empty row in CoderBook/VERA sheet

            'look for Id match in destination sheet
            m = Application.Match(Ophth.Range("A" & i).Value, VERA.Columns(1), 0)
            If IsError(m) Then
                'no match on Id - copy values
                VERA.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Value = _
                                                               Ophth.Rows(i).Value
            End If

    End Select
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: It is working beautifully! Mind checking my logic? I am desperately trying to learn as I go.   [m = Application.Match(Ophth.Range("A" & i).Value, VERA.Columns(1), 0)] *says: check the values in column A on Ophth sheet against the 1st column (column A) on VERA sheet.   [If IsError(m) Then_VERA.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Value=                                                              Ophth.Rows(i).Value]   *says:? could you "translate" this one for me to help me understand? I have always avoided "offset" in excel due to volatility, but have never seen it in VBA.

Comment: There's no reason to avoid offset in code like this: maybe if you were writing a UDF it might be an issue.  The line does the same as your copy/paste values but avoids the copy/paste by assigning the row values directly.  `Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)` = Starting at the last cell in ColA perform Ctrl+Up to find the last occupied cell, then offset one row down from there

Comment: Awesome!  So what part is actually telling it to copy?  the "EntireRow.Value"?  Sorry for the newbie questions, gotta start somewhere!

Comment: Yes it sets `Value = Value` directly which is the same as copy/paste values

Comment: Nevermind, re-reading your comment for the 5th time I think I get it - it is literally just telling it "hey make these values the same as these values."

Comment: Thank you so, so, so much for your help and teaching on this!!